# Is there a way to split a string after a certain number of characters in Java?

Tags: java, string, split

Say I have a string "yyyymmddword", Is there a method I could use to have an int year, month, day, and String word based on that string. 
So if I have a string "20070405word", I need to convert it to:

```
String name = "yyyymmddword";
int year = 2007;
int day = 04;
int month = 05;
String word = "word";
```

How can I write a method that can allow me to split that string without manually assigning these variables?

Comment: `String.substring()` ?

Comment: Either use built-in formatters and parsers that are designed specificaly for working with dates (use java.time, NOT java.util.Date and all this toxic waste). If this doesn't work for your use-case, then use `java.util.Pattern`, use something like `(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\w+)` as regex and then use `Matcher.group` to access each component. Come back when you have some code, even if it's not quite right. The more important point is: you probably really don't want to have integer variables "year", "day" and "month" anywhere in your code, because getting it right is *hell*.

Comment: You have 4 variables. You cannot assign to them, without "manually" doing so *(ignoring reflection)*.

Comment: No, there is not a function that will do all of this for you. You will need to write it yourself using `String.substring()`.

Answer (score 0):

To base purely off the index of the character `String.substring()` is perfectly suitable.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s = "yyyymmddword";

    System.out.println(s.substring(0,4));
    System.out.println(s.substring(4,6));
    System.out.println(s.substring(6,8));
    System.out.println(s.substring(8));        
}
```

---

Output:

```
yyyy
mm
dd
word
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String name = "yyyymmddword";
int year = Integer.parseInt(name.substring(0, 4));
int day = Integer.parseInt(name.substring(4, 6));
int month = Integer.parseInt(name.substring(6, 8));
String year = Integer.parseInt(name.substring(8));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. All you need to do is create more Strings, then use the substring() method. Follow my example below.

```
    String word = "TestString";
    String new1 = word.substring(0,4); 
    /*substring() goes from the first specified index, up to, but not including
    * the second.
    */
    String new2 = word.substring(4,word.length() + 1);
    System.out.println(word + "\n" + new1 + "\n" + new2);
```